# Is there a Repeat-Until in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make my character shoot in pygame. I cannot get the bullet to move from his position, and stop if it hits the edge of the screen. What I would like is for it to continue moving, until it collides with the screen edge. Whenever I run the following code, it crashes:

```
class BULLET(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, speed, location):
    self.pos = [0,0]
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = SHOWBULLET
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
    self.rect.center = location
    self.speed = speed
def move(self):
    if AMMO > 0:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and Gun.image == NOGUN:
            held_down = True
            if held_down == True:
                self.rect.centerx = Player.rect.centerx
                self.rect.centery = Player.rect.centery
                if Player.direction == 0:
                    self.direction = 0
                    while self.rect.top >= screen.get_rect().top:
                        self.rect.top = self.rect.top + 20
                        if self.rect.top <=   screen.get_rect().top:
                            break
```

Comment: Isn't repeat until just while(Condition not met): ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine you would like to structure your game this way. This is an abbreviated version containing what I thought was relevant and there are some problems with it, but in essence

- Your bullet shouldn't care about the player at all after it is fired.
- The bullet should start where the player was standing at the time of the HoldMouseButton Event. After that, it should continue on it's path uninterrupted.
- I'd think you would want the player to shoot many bullets if the mouse is held down for a long time. I don't think your current code does that. Really, the bullet should care about any events at all except TickEvents which help it move on the screen. The player, on the other hand, should care about the mouse button being held down, and should fire bullets as long as the mouse button is held down.
- Additionally, learning a bit about MVC architecture might be of help. Check out this [basic tutorial](http://ezide.com/games/writing-games.html).

Hope this helps.

```
class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, velocity, start_position):
        self.pos = start_position
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.visible = True

    def notify(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, TickEvent):
            self.move(event.time_passed)

    def move(self, time):
        self.pos += velocity * time

class Charactor:
    def __init__(self, position, event_manager, sprite_manager, etc.):
        self.state = 'MOVING'
        self.pos = position
        self.direction = direction

    def notify(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, HoldMouseButtonEvent()):
            self.state = 'SHOOTING'
        elif isinstance(event, ReleaseMouseButtonEvent()):
            self.state = 'MOVING'
        elif isinstance(event, TickEvent()):
            if self.state == 'SHOOTING':
                self.shoot()
            elif self.state == 'MOVING':
                self.move()

    def shoot(self):
        sprite_manager.add(Bullet(BULLET_VELOCITY * self.direction, self.pos))
```

Answer (score 0):

your move function should ignore everything to do with the player. Start from scratch with it.  It should update its position every tick (maybe by calling `move()` every tick) and it should go in its own direction and check its own collision with walls/edges

Fixed your init method

```
def __init__(self, speed, location, direction):
    self.pos = location
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = SHOWBULLET
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
    self.rect.center = location
    self.speed = speed
    self.direction = direction
```

Your move method, however probably needs to be redone from scratch

There should be 2 parts to your move method:

1) move the bullet one increment in the direction that you want

```
if (direction == 0) {
    self.pos = newPosition; // replace new position with a calculation for up
} else if (direction == 1) {
    self.pos = newPosition; // this new position should be one increment right
} etc...
```

2) Check to see if the bullet is off of the screen

```
if (self.pos[0] > width || self.pos[0] < 0 || self.pos[1] > height || self.pos[1] < 0) {
    //return false;
}

return true;
```

Comment: See, the bullets origin is where the player is, therefore, starting to move from the player's position, like a real gun

Comment: you should do all of that in `__init__()` because that is where the bullet STARTS @user2493744

Comment: @user2493744 - have you tried it? it should work. the bullet shouldn't care about the players position after it's been shot anymore. Although that would allow for some cool shooting tricks. Move to the side while the bullet flies and you can shoot around a corner...

Comment: @user2493744 when you create the bullet you should pass it the player's location like this `bullet = Bullet(10, Player.pos)`

Comment: I need it to move to the players position, when it is first shot, then to move away from the player, therefore simulating it leaving the barrel, and moving away in the direction the player is facing

Comment: @user2493744 correct, somebody else asked this same question yesterday, You need to have a direction as a parameter to your init method as well `__init__(self, velocity, start_postion, direction)`

Comment: how do i get it to repeatedly move until it touches the screen?

Comment: in your main while loop, say myBullet.move() and then it will run that function on every time tick @user2493744

Comment: Could you update your answer so i could see what your talking about, ie. full bullet class and its part in the main loop?

Comment: Thanks for the __init__ fix, can you get me started on the move method, please?

Comment: @user2493744 any more questions? i just got off of work and have some more time